# Understanding Thm. 13.6 in Bruckner's Real Analysis (completeness of $L^{\infty}$)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

In the following is Theorem 13.6 from Bruckner's Real Analysis which I don't understand some claims on it :

Question *in Blue:* $\mu (|f_j(x)| > \|f_j\|_∞)=0$ and $\mu (|f_k(x)| > \|f_k\|_∞)=0$. But how that implies $\mu (|f_j(x) - f_k(x)| > \|f_k\|_∞)=0$?

Question *in Green:* It is clear that $f$ is bounded and is the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $f$. How that convergence is uniform?

> **Theorem 13.6** *Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Then the space $L_{\infty}(\mu)$ is a Banach space furnished with the norm $\|f\|_{\infty} .$*
>
> **Proof.** It is easy to see that a linear combination of essentially bounded functions remains essentially bounded, and so the space is linear. It is almost immediate that $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is a norm on this space. The triangle inequality, that
> $$
> \|f+g\|_{\infty} \leq\|f\|_{\infty}+\|g\|_{\infty}
> $$
> (which can also be considered as the extension of Minkowski's inequality to the case $p=\infty$ ), follows from the set inclusion
> $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> \left\{x:|f(x)+g(x)|>\|f\|_{\infty}+\|g\|_{\infty}\right\} \\
> \subset\left\{x:|f(x)|>\|f\|_{\infty}\right\} \cup\left\{x:|g(x)|>\|g\|_{\infty}\right\}.
> \end{array}
> $$
> Exercise 13:3.2 shows that each of the sets on the right side of the inclusion has $\mu$ -measure zero and so, too, must the set on the left. This gives the triangle inequality.
>
> $\quad$The completeness part of the proof is rather simpler than the completeness proof for the $L_{p}$ spaces with $1 \leq p<\infty$. Let $\left\{f_{n}\right\}$ be Cauchy in $L_{\infty}(\mu)$. Define $A_{i}$ to be the set of points $x$ in $X$ for which $\left|f_{i}(x)\right|>\left\|f_{i}\right\|_{\infty}$, and define $\color{blue}{B_{j, k}}$ to be the set of points $x$ in $X$ for which $\left|f_{j}(x)-f_{k}(x)\right|>\left\|f_{k}\right\|_{\infty}$. All these sets $\color{blue}{\text{have measure zero by definition}}$. Let $E$ be the totality of all these points, that is, the union of these sets taken over all integers $i, j, k$. Then $E$ has measure zero, and the sequence $\left\{f_{n}(x)\right\}$ converges for every $x \in X \backslash E$, and indeed $\color{green}{\text{it converges uniformly to some bounded function $f$}}$ defined on $X \backslash E .$ We can extend $f$ to all of $X$ in any arbitrary fashion [or simply set $f(x)=0$ for $x \in E]$, and it is easy to see that $f \in L_{\infty}(\mu)$ and that $\left\|f-f_{n}\right\|_{\infty} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.$\blacksquare$

[(Original screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnVp1.jpg)

Question 3 : Exercise 13:3.1 says that a sequence $f_n$ converges to a function $f$ in the space $L_∞(X, M,μ)$ if and only if there is a set $E ∈M$ with $μ(E)=0$ so
that $f_n → f$ uniformly on $X \setminus E$. One direction is the "Green" question, for the other direction, isn't it a convention/definition rather than a theorem?

Comment: I mean that there's a big wall of text you've screenshotted and not bothered to type up.

Comment: Please also only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun: The O.P. is just being smart enough not to type something that is clear form his picture. What is the problem with being smart?

Comment: @Shaun, Do you want me to post several questions in several posts when they are about "proof-explanation" of ONE theorem?! Then you will write : "please don't send it in many questions as they are related"!

Comment: @JeanL. With images, it's much harder to find this question from google.

Comment: @DavidLui, then let me make it easy to find. I'll edit my post. Btw, typing a long text seems very time consuming instead of spending on learning.

Comment: @DavidLui: What matters, for a google search, is the context "completeness of $L_\infty$ or something like that. Who cares if google can't find this specific question among hundreds of similar questions. What the OP did seems fine to me.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, thanks, Oliver. Actually it is easy to find it when I've written the name of the theorem and from the typed questions I've asked, google will find this post. No need to re-write a large text.

Comment: @L.G. Answering your questions is time consuming but people take the time to do it. Take the time to write your answer properly so that it is searchable and can be found by others with the same question. It's not that difficult.

Comment: I used a program called mathpix to do it in less than 30 seconds (a further minute or so to reproduce the colours). Typing the question manually arguably has its benefits (e.g. forcing you to read each word one by one). I personally cannot access imgur from my work so I cannot answer questions that require an image. In the case of pictures of text, this can be remedied. Also, relying on colour to tag your question would mean that colour-blind people cannot easily know which question is which (but they can inspect my latex code to find the colour now)

Comment: There has already been many discussions on the meta site regarding large pictures of text. Here are some: [link1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions), [link2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31790/using-text-and-mathjax-instead-of-screenshot/31840#31840), [link3](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11696/should-i-edit-a-question-everytime-i-see-an-image-in-it). It seems to me that the consensus is that if such a picture is added, the question should still be able to stand alone without the picture.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, I will try that program Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a typo in your textbook.

I am writing here a proof that is closed to your text's. Suppose $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L_\infty(\mu)$. Then for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that
$$\begin{align}
\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty<\varepsilon,\qquad n,m\geq N\tag{0}\label{0}\end{align}$$
As it is mentioned in your book

1. $\mu(|f_n|>\|f_n\|_\infty)=0$
2. $\mu(|f_m-f_n|>\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty)=0$.

It follows that the set $A=\bigcup_n\{|f_n|>\|f_n\|_\infty)\cup\bigcup_{n,m}\{|f_n-f_m|>\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty\}$, being the union of countable sets of measure $0$, has measure $0$. Setting $B=X\setminus A$, we have from \eqref{0} that
$$\begin{align}
|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \|f_n-f_n\|<\varepsilon ,\qquad n, m\geq N,\,x\in B\tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}$$
This argument shows that on $B$, $f_n$ converges uniformly. Define $f(x)$ to be $0$ if $x\in A$ and $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(X)$ for $x\in B$ (this is well defined since $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $B$).
Passing to the limit $m\rightarrow\infty$ in \eqref{1} gives you that
$$|f_n(f)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon,\qquad n\geq N,\, x\in B$$
Since $\mu(A)>0$,
$\|f-f_n\|_\infty\leq\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Since $\|f_n(x)\|\leq \varepsilon+\|f_N(x)\|_\infty:=C_\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and $x\in B$,  $f$ is bounded by $C_\varepsilon$ in $B$. This means that $\|f\|_\infty\leq C_\varepsilon$.

**Notes:**

- If a function $f$ is bounded on a measurable set $E$ by say, a constant  $C>0$, and $\mu(E^c)=0$, then $\mu(|f|>C)\leq\mu(E^c)=0$. Consequently,  from the definition of $\|f\|_\infty$, it follows that

1. $f\in L_\infty(\mu)$,
2. $\|f\|_\infty\leq C$.

Proof: Recall that $\|f\|_\infty=\inf\{a>0:\mu(|f|>a)=0\}$. The assumption on $f$ implies that $C\in\mathcal{E}=\{a>0:\mu(|f|>a)=0\}$. Hence $\|f\|_\infty\leq C$.

- Another important property of $\|f\|_\infty$ that is used implicitly is the fact that $\mu(|f|>\|f\|_\infty)=0$.

Proof: Let $\mathcal{E}$ be as before. For any $a>0$, if $a>\|f\|_\infty$, then $a\in \mathcal{E}$. To see this, suppose $a>\|f\|_\infty$. Then,  by definition of $\|f\|_\infty$, there is $b\in \mathcal{E}$ such that $\|f\|_\infty\leq b<a$. Then $\mu(|f|>a)\leq \mu(|f|>b)=0$; thus, $a\in \mathcal{E}$. Finally, let $a_n\in\mathcal{E}$ such that $a_n>\|f\|_\infty$ and $a_n\searrow\|f\|_\infty$. Then
$\mu(|f|>\|f\|_\infty\}=\bigcup_n\{|f|>a_n\}$ whence we conclude that
$$\mu(|f|>\|f\|_\infty)=\lim_n\mu(|f|>a_n)=0$$

Comment: My question is how uniform Cauchy and pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence?

Comment: @L.G. Notice that if $g$ is bounded in a set $E$, say $|g(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in E$, and $\mu(E^c)=0$, then $g\in L_\infty$ and $\|g\|_\infty\leq M$. Indeed,  $\mu(|g|>M)\leq \mu(E^c)=0$. By Definition $\|g\|_\infty=\inf\{a>0:\mu(|g|>a)=0$, therefore, $\|g\|_\infty\leq M$. I hope this helps you understand JeanL's solution as well as his/her comment.

Comment: Thank you Jean :)

Answer (score -1):

$B_{j,k}$ needs not have measure zero.
For, if $f_k$ is a constant function with $f_k =-1$,
then $||f_k||_\infty = 1$.
If $f_j$ is another constant function with $f_j=1$,
then $ | f_j(x) - f_k(x) | = 2 > ||f_k||_\infty$ for all $x$.

There must be some typos (or even gaps) in the proof. You may need to fix them by yourself.

Remark: It is worth mentioning that elements in $L^\infty$ are not bounded measurable functions. They are equivalent classes of essentially bounded measurable functions. Let $([f_n])_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L^\infty$. When you pick a representative $f_n$ from the equivalent class $[f_n]$, you need to pay attention that your argument should be independent of choice of representative.

In order to have the duality $(L^1)^\ast = L^\infty$, if $\mu$ is not $\sigma$ finite, you need to modify the definition of "essential upper bound" by replacing $\mu$-null set with $\mu$-locally null set.
See [Definition of $L^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088761/definition-of-l-infty).

Comment: Jean L. pointed out in her answer that there is a typo in textbook. It should have been $B_{j,k}=\{|f_j-f_k|>\|f_n-f_k\|_\infty\}$, which of course has measure $0$.

Comment: In the original screenshot, the RHS is $||f_k||_\infty$ but not $||f_j-f_k||_\infty$. That part is underlined in blue color.

Comment: The author of the book the OP is using defined $\|f\|_\infty$ as the essential supremum, that is $\|f\|_\infty:=\inf\{a>0:\mu(|f|>a)=0\}$, so no issue with $\sigma$--finiteness is needed attention at this point.

Answer (score -1):

An easier way to prove that the norm of a normed space is complete
is to invoke the following result:

Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a norm space. Then the norm is complete if
and only if for every sequence $(x_{n})$ in $X$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||x_{n}||<\infty\Rightarrow$
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}$ converges.

Assume the above standard result in functional analysis. For your
question: Let $(\alpha_{n})$ be a sequence in $L^{\infty}$ such that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||\alpha_{n}||<\infty$. For each $n$, pick a
representative $f_{n}\in\alpha_{n}$. Define $A_{n}=\{x\in X\mid|f_{n}(x)|>||\alpha_{n}||\}$,
then $\mu(A_{n})=0$. (Warning! If $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite, $A_n$ is just locally null, in the sense that for any measurable set $C$ with $\mu(C)<\infty$, we have that $\mu(C\cap A_n)=0$. Moreover, in the following, $B^c$ is just a $\mu$-locally null set. In this proof, we assume that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.)

Let $B=X\setminus\cup_{n}A_{n}$. For each $x\in B$,
we have that $|f_{n}(x)|\leq||\alpha_{n}||$. Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_{n}(x)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||\alpha_{n}||<\infty$.
By completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ converges.
Let $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}1_{B}$, which is measurable because
it is pointwise limit of measurable functions. Moreover, for each
$x\in X$, $|f(x)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}||\alpha_{n}||<\infty$,
so $f$ is bounded. Finally, go to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_{n}\rightarrow[f]$
with respect to the norm $||\cdot||$.

Note that a representative of $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_{n}$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_{n}$.
For each $x\in B$, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_{n}(x)\right|\\
 & = & \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_{n}(x)\right|\\
 & \leq & \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|f_{n}(x)|\\
 & \leq & \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}||\alpha_{n}||.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $\{x\in X\mid\left|f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}f_{n}(x)\right|>\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}||\alpha_{n}||\}\subseteq B^{c}$
which has measure zero. That is, $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}||\alpha_{n}||$
is an essential upper bound of $|f-\sum_{n=1}^{N}|$. Hence, $||[f]-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_{n}||\leq\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}||\alpha_{n}||\rightarrow0$
as $N\rightarrow\infty$. This shows that $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_{n}\rightarrow[f]$
with respect to $||\cdot||_{\infty}$-norm.