# Riesz-Fischer in $L^\infty$ clarification needed.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

This is Rudin's RCA book. He discusses completeness of $L^\infty(\mu)$, but there is a part of proof that I don't understand.

> In $L^\infty(\mu)$, suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and let $A_k, B_{m,n}$ be the sets where $|f_k(x)| > \|f_k\|_\infty$ and $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| > \|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$, and let $E$ be the union of these sets, for $k, m ,n = 1,2,3, \cdots$. Then, $\mu(E)=0$, and on the completement of $E$, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to a bounded function $f$. Define $f(x) = 0$ on $E$. Then, $f \in L^\infty(\mu)$ and $\|f_n - f\|_\infty \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Since $f$ is a complex function, I understand that $f_k$ converges to some measurable complex function $f$. The part that I do not understand is 1. (almost everywhere) boundedness, and 2. (a.e.) uniform convergence. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: THe set $E$ being the countable union of sets of measure zero has also measure zero. If $x\notin  E$ then $|f_k(x)|\leq \|f_k\|_\infty$ for all $k$, and also $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \|f_n-f_m\|$ for all $n,m$, Since $f_m$ is Cauchy in $L_\infty$, then the numeric sequence $f_m(x)$ is bounded and Cauchy and so it converges to a finite number, say $f(x)$. This happens for each $x\notin E$ (hence the almost everywhere)

Comment: Thanks. It showed 1. What about 2.? For a.e. $x$ (for simplicity, I'll denote it is $\forall x$), $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq \|f_n-f_m\|$. Hence, I have a uniform Cauchy $\forall x \in X$. How does this imply that $\{f_n\}$ uniformly converges to $f$?

Comment: @Resolved. $|f(x) - f_n(x)| = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} |f_m(x) - f_n(X)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that $n,m\geq N$ implies $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$. Now, for all $x\notin E$, for all $n\geq N$,  you have $$|f(x)-f_n(x)|=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\liminf_m\|f_m-f_n\|_\infty\leq\varepsilon$$ This implies that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $E^c$.

Comment: You may rewrite your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to know all is resolved now.

Comment: This has been asked before and I rather keep it as comment. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4174126/121671) is a good answer to your question. You may upvote this one if you want.