# Prove that $\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}=\sup\{\lambda:\mu \{ x: |f(x)|>\lambda \}>0\} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

By definition we know that

$$\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}=\inf\{M:\mu \{ x: |f(x)|>M \}=0\}.$$

We note that for each pair $(\lambda, M)$ such that $\mu\{x:|f(x)|>M\}=0$ and $\mu\{x:|f(x)|>\lambda\}>0$ we have $\lambda < M$. Suppose the contrary, then $\lambda \geq M$. Therefore,
$$\{x:|f(x)|>\lambda \} \subset \{x:|f(x)|>M \},$$
which implies that
$$0<\mu \{x:|f(x)|>\lambda \} \leq\mu \{x:|f(x)|>M \}=0,$$
which is a contradiction. Thus,
$$\sup \{\lambda: \mu \{x:|f(x)|>\lambda\}>0\} \leq \inf\{M:\mu\{x:|f(x)|>M\}=0\}.$$

**My question:** How to prove the other inequality, that is, how to show that
$$\sup \{\lambda: \mu \{x:|f(x)|>\lambda\}>0\} \geq \inf\{M:\mu\{x:|f(x)|>M\}=0\}?$$

**My attempt:** Let $K$ be defined by $K=\sup \{\lambda: \mu \{x:|f(x)|>\lambda\}>0\}$. Suppose that $M \in (K,\infty)$ then $\mu\{x:|f(x)|>M\}=0$. Indeed, if we had $M>K$ with $\mu\{x:|f(x)|>M\}>0$ this would be a contradiction with the definition of upper bound. Hence,
$$(K,\infty) \subset \{M:\mu\{x:|f(x)|>M\}=0\}$$
which implies that
$$\inf\{M:\mu\{x:|f(x)|>M\}=0\} \leq \inf (K,\infty)= K=\sup \{\lambda: \mu \{x:|f(x)|>\lambda\}>0\}.$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: To spice things up a little, I would like to mention that there is another definition of infinity norm defined as $\|f\|^*_\infty=\inf\{M>0: \mu(A\cap\{|f|>M\})=0,\qquad \forall \,A,\text{with}\,\mu(A)<\infty\}$. This is a "local" essential supremum. When the space $X$ is $\sigma$-finite, both notions of norm coincide.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Is it easy to prove this equivalence?

Comment: It is not complicated. Start by writing $X=\bigcup_nA_n$ where $A_n$ are integrable sets of finite positive measure (If $X$ has finite measure there is nothing to do). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3697466/121671) is a posting that discusses this a little. But let's not deviate from your main question in the OP. Have you manage to solve the issues you had?

Comment: I believe I managed to solve the problem, thanks for the reference.